# CMake separate flags for Assembler

Tags: assembly, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile a project for an ARM target, using the GCC cross compiler. I created  a target and set things like ABI flags (-mcpu, -mfpu etc.) with target_compile_options() and defines which target_compile_definitions(). However, I now have the issue that these flags are passed to the assembler call as well. Is there a way to use separate assembler flags for the assembler call?

```
[ 65%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fsfw_example.dir/bsp_stm32/main.cpp.obj
arm-none-eabi-g++ -DSTM32H743xx -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER 
-Ibla\bla <more includes here> -g -specs=nosys.specs 
-specs=nano.specs -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard 
-mthumb -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections 
-std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles\fsfw_example.dir\bsp_stm32\main.cpp.obj 
-c C:\Users\Robin\Documents\FSFW\fsfw_example\bsp_stm32\main.cpp

[ 66%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/fsfw_example.dir/bsp_stm32/startup_stm32h743xx.s.obj
    arm-none-eabi-as -DSTM32H743xx -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -Ibla\bla <more includes here> 
-mcpu=cortex-m7;-mfpu=fpv5-d16;-mfloat-abi=hard;-mthumb -g -specs=nosys.specs 
-specs=nano.specs -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb 
-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -o CMakeFiles\fsfw_example.dir\bsp_stm32\startup_stm32h743xx.s.obj 
-c C:\Users\Robin\Documents\FSFW\fsfw_example\bsp_stm32\startup_stm32h743xx.s
```

Problem is: The arm-none-eabi-as is not able to process the defines. Is it possible to remove them for the assembler compilation process specifically?
I also tried to set source specific flags but that does not appear to work, the target compile options/defines appear to have priority.

Kind Regards
Robin

Comment: you are calling the assembler with the same flags as the compiler?

Comment: CMake is doing that. It is because somehow, the compile flags I add with target_...() are added to the assembler call as well.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by using the arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler with the -x assembler-with-cpp option as the CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER, to get GCC to run it through the C preprocessor before assembling. I used generator expressions for that:

```
target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:${C_DEFS} ${C_FLAGS}>
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:${CXX_DEFS} ${CXX_FLAGS}>
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:ASM>:-x assembler-with-cpp ${ASM_FLAGS}>
)
```

Using `arm-none-eabi-as` can only handle assembler directives like `.macro`, not CPP directives like `#define` (CPP is needed for that).  Using `as` directly, lines with `#` probably get treated as comments.

Comment: `gcc -c foo.S`  will run your asm through the C preprocessor (before feeding it to `as`) *if* the filename has a `.S` (capital S) extension, not for lower-case `.s`.  If you want to override that, yes `-x <language>` can be used, in this case `-x assembler-with-cpp`.  (Not `-x assembler`, that's already the default for `.s` files).  Use `gcc -v foo.S` to see what it runs.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that clarifies a lot :-) I adapted my CMake files accordingly

Comment: Edits should remove wrong attempts that future readers shouldn't use, not just tack on more stuff with "Edit:" or "Update:".  Just make the answer into what will be most helpful to future readers.  I did that for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding a separate library target for the assembler code, and linking this library to the final executable:

```
add_library(assembler_parts startup_stm32h743xx.s)
target_link_libraries(my_executable assembler_parts)
```

Since `assembler_parts` is a different target, it does not share the target specific options, e.g. those set via `target_compile_options(my_executable ...)`.